# how to hide the user list icon from mesibo in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mesibo

I am using mesibo_flutter_sdk 2.2.0 for chats, but there is no option to hide the user list icon. Please find attached the screenshot below.

[image]

I checked MesiboUIOptions, but there is no option available to hide the user list icon.

**Code:**
void initMesibo(String token) async {

```
// Future<String> asyncAppId = _mesibo.getAppIdForAccessToken();
// asyncAppId.then((String appid) { mAppId = appid; });



_mesibo.setAccessToken(token);
_mesibo.setListener(this);
_mesibo.start();
_mesiboUi.getUiDefaults().then((MesiboUIOptions options) {
  options.enableBackButton = true;

  options.appName = "Chats";
  options.userOnlineIndicationTitle="Online";
  options.toolbarColor = 0xFF73ad00;
  options.statusBarColor = 0xFF73ad00;
  _mesiboUi.setUiDefaults(options);
});



MesiboUIButtons buttons = MesiboUIButtons();
buttons.message = false;
buttons.audioCall = true;
buttons.videoCall = true;
buttons.groupAudioCall = true;
buttons.groupVideoCall = true;
buttons.endToEndEncryptionInfo = false; // e2ee should be enabled
_mesiboUi.setupBasicCustomization(buttons, null);
}
```

Comment: could you share the code you're working with?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please avoid "solved" type terms in questions. It's enough to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to customize buttons in a Mesibo UI is by defining a UI listener in native code, as explained in the Mesibo documentation here:

https://docs.mesibo.com/ui-modules/customizing/

For Flutter, basic button customization can be done by setting properties on the MesiboUIButtons object, set `buttons.message = false`:

```
MesiboUIButtons buttons = MesiboUIButtons();
buttons.message = false;
buttons.audioCall = true;
buttons.videoCall = true;
buttons.groupAudioCall = true;
buttons.groupVideoCall = true;
buttons.endToEndEncryptionInfo = false;  
_mesiboUi.setupBasicCustomization(buttons, null);
```

Refer to this Flutter sample code for an implementation:

https://github.com/mesibo/samples/blob/master/flutter/firstapp/lib/main.dart#L270

Answer (score 0):

if the solution proposed to Meisbo itself does not work for you for some reason i'm proposing another one:

We can create a custom layout for your chat interface instead of using the built-in Mesibo UI:

```dart
class CustomChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Custom Chat'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: messages.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text(messages[index]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                 controller: messageController,
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Type a message',
                 ),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                onPressed: () {
                 // Handle send button press
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
 }
}
```

Here `messages` is a list of strings representing the messages in the chat, and `messageController` is a `TextEditingController` for the text field where the user types their message. When the send button is pressed, you would handle sending the message and updating the `messages` list accordingly.

This is a starting point you will need to add some features such as displaying the sender of each message or handling media attachments.

this approach requires a lot of labor and you have to manully manage all aspect of the chat interface

Comment: Now working fine with new version